# Solve ODE IVP with different conditions in finite Real range

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, interval-arithmetic

How to I approach the following problem?

Suppose $\phi (x) : [0,5] \rightarrow [0,1] $ is an IVP given by:

$$\phi (x) := \left \{ \begin{array}{l} x, \forall x \in [0,1] \\ 1, \forall x \in (1,5] \end{array}\right. $$

Find the solution $f(x) : [1,5) \rightarrow \Re $ of the initial value problem

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \phi (x) $$ where $$ f(0)=1 $$

and show your solution is differentiable on $(0,5)$.

Comment: !!! Sorry, the second interval is (1,5] NOT (0,5]

Comment: You can edit your question. This is not really an ODE, it is just a quadrature problem a the right side does not depend on $f$. So you just have to determine an anti-derivative of the right side with a suitable integration constant.